# Why does some of the DAPP uses PHP and how would they do so?

Tags: solidity, web3js, php, web3.php

I always wonder how come many DAPPS uses PHP extension at the end of the filename and how did they do so ?? There is slighlty possibility that they are using the Web3PHP library to interact with the Smart contract..if this is the case, then why are they using web3Js as well...It makes no sense to use both of the libraries..Do they use both centralized and decentralized approach for Dapps?? **How do they use PHP with DAPPS**..???

Answer (score 2):

Both web3js and web3php are just libraries to communicate with the Ethereum blockchain.

You can ask through a browser (then you'd use web3js), or from a server (then you'd use web3php), some information (like, what's the balance of this address, or call some contract's method to read something).